# добавления события для кнопки

Tags: vb.net

Скажите пожалуйста есть вот такая зкдача
Есть кнопка которая создаеться в процессе работы программы 
Нужно сделать так что бы при нажитие на кнопку выполнялос какое либо действие 
Но при этом этих кнопок может быть не ограниченое кол-во
И если можно напишите коментарии
и для каждой кнопки должно быть свое сообытия

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AddHandler Btn.Click, AddressOf HandlerMouseClik
```

Где создание EventHandler следует предосавить Visual Studio. (она сама добавит нудные параметры)

Comment: Поясните пожалуйсто ни чего не понел

Comment: Ну, короче обработчик нужно создавать с параметрами, их можно написать вручную или Visual Studio это сделает автоматически.
![Ошибка](http://i.imm.io/Qa7T.png)